Where to find the first nal unit in the mdat payload of an MPEG4 file containing h265 video?
in my quest for fixing corrupt GoPro files, I am writing a decoder based on an MPEG4 parsing lib, but I now have to dig deeper in the h265 stream, and I'm having a hard time finding where the first NAL unit starts.
I read that the mdat box starts with its header of course (size and 'mdat') followed by NAL units, and that each NAL unit starts with its size coded on 32 bits.
However, in a test file, the mdat box starts as follows:
01 6c 49 56 6d 64 61 74 47 50 52 4f 6c 02 00 00
48 44 38 2e 30 31 2e 30 32 2e 35 31 2e 30 30 43 
33 33 34 31 33 32 36 37 37 38 31 35 34 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f1 
82 0c 83 79 06 7e 42 45 b3 a8 f0 62 6f cc 2e 43 
33 33 33 31 33 35 31 36 39 38 35 30 38 00 48 45 
52 4f 38 20 42 6c 61 63 6b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0c 1e 00 ce 


That I would start decoding as:
01 6c 49 56 => size 0x01634956: OK
6d 64 61 74 => 'mdat': OK
47 50 52 4f 6c => 'GPRO1' ??? That cannot be not a size or NAL unit header.

In the next bytes following the above, I can find other ascii strings such as a serial number of the camera, model name, firwmare version probably, etc, then words such as HIGH and AUTO, and many groups of 00 bytes that clearly are not part of compressed video.
As far as I can tell, real "random" (or rather 'unpredicatable') bytes only start around 850 bytes after the start of the mdat box.
Any idea what this header is and how to determine where the actual NAL units start?

'mdat' can contain pretty much anything.

video
audio
real-time metadata
timecode

So this is a little bit like turning a Hamburger back into a cow.
I would take the GoPro and make a new recording with the same settings.
Same video resolution, bitrate and audio quality.
From the new recording - you can learn how the camera interleaves video, audio and metadata. I am guessing that the camera will use a somewhat fixed pattern.
A correct MP4 file will contain essential metadata of the video stream that is probably not available in your corrupt file. So you need to copy this metadata from the newly recorded file.
I would take the newly recorded video and use ffmpeg to copy the H.265 stream into an elementary stream. Now you have a target format that you want to use.
You'll have a template that shows you were to insert AUDs, PPS, SPS etc.
This should enable you to reconstruct the video stream.
This is not a super simple task and will require understanding the MPEG-4 container and the H.265 stream syntax.

Thanks Markus. I have plenty of OK recordings from that GoPro, but without a full decoder, it's not like a diff would show what to patch ;-). At the MPEG4 wrapper level at least, the structure is identical, same boxes at the same place... I admit I have started reading the spec of H265 but while the MPEG4 wrapper logic is "quite straightforward", the H265 decoding is on another level...
I think I'll have to abandon the idea :-(

OK, I found the answer to my question:
The position of the video/audio/... data in the mdat segment can be found as 32-bit offsets in the stco box. Just beware that these offsets are based on the position in the file, not in the mdat payload.
If the file is more than 4GB, 32 bits are not enough and the 'co64' box replaces the 'stco' box, with 64-bit addresses.
In my example, the first 'stco' record of the video track indeed points a few hundred bytes after the start of the mdat, on the first byte of a NAL unit.
The first part (beginning with GPro) is pointed to by a 'stco' record of the metadata track.
